# TEC2-25408 - 8A 12 V - goes max at -20° 4A

Tags: power-supply

I have tried to power that pelletier module with an AT power supply but I reached max -10°C or something

I ordered a 12V 10A power supply, as I measure the peltier module, it really does not go up to specs.

Barely -20°C (should <-30°C)
and current is only half of the specified current

Peltier:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32386272344.html?spm=a2g0s.12269583.0.0.662f6f04RWvMLA

Power supply:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32990203636.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.3da24c4d7hBp9i

Fan:
I am using a 12V fan with a 10x10x4cm CPU fan

What am I missing ?

Comment: We don't expect every post to be perfect, but posts with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get read and upvoted more frequently. Remember, you can always go back at any time and edit your post to improve it. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages. You appear to have linked to web sales pages rather than datasheets for the products. Our advice: "No datasheet? No sale!"

Answer (score 3):

The "specs" are likely for no heat load, the graph below is likely the information for the same module but there is no way to be sure. Either way, the graph shows the relation between heat flow and temperature across a module (if not the module, if you want to be sure, go find the manufacturer and see if the data is supplied). As the heat load increases, the modules ability to drive the cold side to lower temperatures drops.

[image]
Source: http://www.huimao.com/series2.htm

The coldest temperature can be determined by the heat load and the ambient temperature.

For example, with 5W of heat pumped and an the hot side of the peliter temperature of 30C, the deltaT of the module would be 80C and the coldest temperature would be -50C.

With 10W of heat pumped, the hot side of the peliter at 30C yields a deltaT of 60C. The lowest temp would be -30C

With a 15W load, the hot side of the peliter at 30C, deltaT would be 40C, the lowest temperature would be -10C

These numbers above are assuming that you have a fan that can make the hot side of the peltier the same temperature as the air, which won't happen. The fan and heatsink will always be a little bit higher than the air temp, which will further reduce the peltiers ability to get cold, because the hot side will be 5C, 10C or even higher than ambient.

I think -20C sounds about right for an ambient temp of 30C. If your ambient temp is more than 30C, then -20C would be great.

You might have a heat load in the 5W to 10W range and the hot side of the peliter is hotter than you think it is (measure it). Another thing is modules are fragile and easy to damage, it's easy to get cracks in the junctions and then they either don't work at all or have less heat pumping capacity

Answer (score 0):

If the module takes 4 amps after a moment, it is very much OK. The 8 amps specified for the element is the maximum current, not the working current. Peltier elements have terribly bad efficiency when run at max current.

And the setup you describe looks like you are running the module on voltage (tension), not on current. Peltier should be run by current to control the amount of heath transferred. The impedance of the element varies over temperatures and current, so voltage is not a proper way to control the chip. Yet, the elements are often run by voltage for simplicity of circuitry and components; the 127xx modules can be driven from 12V, the 049xx modules from 5V.